# What is 'savedThis' for in the Throttle decorator solution on javascript.info?

Tags: javascript, this, throttling

On the https://javascript.info/call-apply-decorators there is the solution for the Throttling decorator task. I've modified the code to get rid of 'sevedThis' and it works perfectly without it (even with object methods). Could anybody give a real reason to use 'sevedThis' variable in this case and call 'wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs)' instead of 'wrapper(...savedArgs)'?

**Original code:**

```
function throttle(func, ms) {

  let isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs,
    savedThis;

  function wrapper() {

    if (isThrottled) { // (2)
      savedArgs = arguments;
      savedThis = this;
      return;
    }
    isThrottled = true;

    func.apply(this, arguments); // (1)

    setTimeout(function() {
      isThrottled = false; // (3)
      if (savedArgs) {
        wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
        savedArgs = savedThis = null;
      }
    }, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}
```

**Code without 'savedThis':**

```
 function throttle(func, ms) {
  let isThrottled = false,
    savedArgs;

  function wrapper() {
    if (isThrottled) {
      // (2)
      savedArgs = arguments;
      return;
    }
    func.apply(this, arguments); // (1)
    isThrottled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
      isThrottled = false; // (3)
      if (savedArgs) {
        wrapper(...savedArgs);
        savedArgs = null;
      }
    }, ms);
  }
  return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: `arguments` is a live collection of the passed arguments, if your'e throwing that live collection around the script, it can't be properly optimized, which causes performance issues. Currently, in strict mode you can pass `arguments` as it is, because it's not a live object anymore. The 2nd snippet passes a correct `this` only in very few cases, it's not OOP applicable. It's notable, that the destructor is dead slow, if you've some time critical code to execute, use `apply` instead.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet where The 2nd snippet does not pass a correct this?

Comment: [Any example](https://jsfiddle.net/q65fe1c8/) when the code executes the timer will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's more clear.